# Wait for EC2 instance to start

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I have a custom AMI which runs my service. Using the AWS Java SDK, I create an EC2 instance using `RunInstancesRequest` from the AMI. Now before I begin to use my service, I must ensure that the newly created instance is up and running. I poll the instance using:

```
var transitionCompleted = false
while (!transitionCompleted) {
  val currentState = instance.getState.getName
  if (currentState == desiredState) {
    transitionCompleted = true
  }
  if(!transitionCompleted) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(TRANSITION_INTERVAL)
    } catch {
      case e: InterruptedException => e.printStackTrace()
    }
  }
}
```

So when the `currentState` of the instance turns into `desiredState`(which is `running`), I get the status that the instance is ready. However any newly created instance, despite being in `running` state, is not available for immediate use as it is still initializing.

How do I ensure that I return only when I'm able to access the instance and its services? Are there any specific status checks to make?

PS: I use Scala

Comment: if it's http service, just do get request.

Comment: @FatihDonmez: which is like polling the request every N seconds; kinda a hack

Comment: yes, something like that.

Comment: voting to close as "unclear what you are asking", you do not have a definition of "able to access the instance and it's services" and that is the point of the question

Comment: I don't know the java sdk but the js sdk has waitFor functionality: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#instanceStatusOk-waiter - this will tell you if this instance is ok. Realistically though, you probably want to ping a service endpoint to determine health.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking instance [*state*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/InstanceState.html), while what you are actually interested in are the instance [*status*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/InstanceStatus.html) checks. You could use [`describeInstanceStatus`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html#describeInstanceStatus-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.DescribeInstanceStatusRequest-) method from the Amazon Java SDK, but instead of implementing your own polling (in a non-idiomatic Scala) it's better to use a ready solution from the SDK: the [EC2 waiters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/waiters/AmazonEC2Waiters.html).

```
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2._, model._, waiters._

val ec2client: AmazonEC2 = ...

val request = new DescribeInstanceStatusRequest().withInstanceIds(instanceID)

ec2client.waiters.instanceStatusOk.run(
  new WaiterParameters()
    .withRequest(request)
    // Optionally, you can tune the PollingStrategy:
    // .withPollingStrategy(...)
  )
)
```

To customize polling delay and retry strategies of the waiter check the [`PollingStrategy`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/waiters/PollingStrategy.html) documentation.